# Bug in C++ Code: setting one variable to zero causes unrelated variable to become zero

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging

Why does the value of variable n2 get changed to 0 in the below code after the execution of the statement arr[26]={0}; ,(I realised this while debugging)
while memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr)); works perfectly.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int n1,n2;
    int count=0,flag;
    int arr[26] = {0};
    cin>>n1>>n2;
    string box1[n1];
    string box2[n2];

    for(int j=0;j<n1;j++)
    cin>>box1[j];

    for(int j=0;j<n2;j++)
    cin>>box2[j];

    count=0;

    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {   

        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++)
        {
            arr[26]={0}; // after the execution of this statement, n2 changes to 0.. WHY???
            //memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr)); // If i use memset , things work correctly
            cout<<n2<<endl; //n2 becomes zero
            for(int k=0;k<box1[i].length();k++)
                arr[box1[i][k]-'A']++;

            for(int k=0;k<box2[j].length();k++)
                arr[box2[j][k]-'A']++;

            for(int k=0;k<26;k++)
            {
                if(arr[k]>=1)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

    }
    printf("%d",count);
   return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong with :

arr[26] = {0};

Comment: `string box1[n1];string box2[n2];` - This is not valid C++.  You cannot declare arrays using a variable as the number of items.  Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: basically, you have declared `int arr[26] = {0};`, so `arr` has `26` elements (from `0` to `25`) trying to access element in index `26` results in **undefined behaviour** and states bad or incorrect code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare arr as:

```
int arr[26] = {0};
```

Which means valid indexes for it are 0-25, making 26 spots total. Then when you write to `arr[26]`, you are actually writing outside of the array, and overwriting memory that your compiler assigned to `n2`.

If you want to be able to index to 26, you need to declare space for 27 ints:

```
int arr[27] = {0};
```

Also the code:

```
arr[26]={0}; // after the execution of this statement, n2 changes to 0.. WHY???
```

Only assigns to element 26 in the array. It does not zero out the entire array or anything like that. The way to zero the entire array at runtime is with `arr = {0}` or using the `memset` code you already have.

Comment: I suspect the OP actually wants `memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));`, as the comment `// If i use memset , things work correctly` indicates.

Comment: @KenY-N He asks "after the execution of this statement, n2 changes to 0.. WHY???". He already knows that memset fixes the problem.

Comment: *The proper way to zero the entire array at runtime is with the memset* -- This is C++, where zeroing an array can be done using `arr = { 0 };`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, I come from a C background, and I didn't know that. I edited my answer to include your solution too.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - are you sure? With gcc and `-std=c++14` I get an `assigning to an array from an initializer list` error.